# Try to cross compile C++ for Windows on Arch Linux with Clang++

Tags: c++, linux, clang, cross-compiling, clang++

The source code included `window.h` that Linux doesn't have this header, so I try to cross compile to Windows on my Linux.
I installed `llvm` package and follow the cross compiling instruction on [llvm.org](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html).

```sh
clang++ --target=aarch64-pc-win32  -fuse-ld=lld -stdlib=libc++ -o video VideoBG.cpp --verbose
```

It results an include error.

```
clang version 13.0.0
Target: aarch64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
clang-13: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-stdlib=libc++' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
 "/usr/bin/clang-13" -cc1 -triple aarch64-pc-windows-msvc19.14.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -mincremental-linker-compatible --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name VideoBG.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mframe-pointer=none -fmath-errno -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu generic -target-feature +neon -target-abi aapcs -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/home/chunyu/Sites/c++ -resource-dir /usr/lib/clang/13.0.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/home/chunyu/Sites/c++ -ferror-limit 19 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -fms-compatibility-version=19.14 -std=c++14 -fdelayed-template-parsing -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -o /tmp/VideoBG-1dda1d.o -x c++ VideoBG.cpp
clang -cc1 version 13.0.0 based upon LLVM 13.0.0 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include
End of search list.
VideoBG.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'windows.h' file not found
#include <windows.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Is it possible to compile for Windows on Linux with Clang?

Comment: There is a complete tutorial [here](https://jake-shadle.github.io/xwin/). Have you tried that procedure?

Comment: Is this tutorial for Rust only?